# Captivate 7 HTML5 Elements Embedding

Tags: adobe-captivate

I published a page of Captivate 7 as HTML5. It works alone, but when I try to embed it to an existing another bootstrap page, it is not working. Is there anyone who had similar problem and solved?

Regards,
Su Myat

Answer (score 0):

I would use an iframe for this. Captivate HTML5 content is 99% javascript.